# get 4 products in a column by specific ids

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, woocommerce

I have 8 products which are uncategorized and I have displayed them by their specific ids but these 8 products are displaying vertically and I want to display them in 2 columns with 4 products in each column. So how can I do that?
Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php  
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'post__in' => array(659,662,661,660)

);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</a>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: You may use CSS `grid` on your `div` or [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

Comment: Just attach HTML and CSS code -  we can help then

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this may work**

Using a grid system with two columns inside the main `<div>`

```
<style>
.item1{grid-area:firstCol;}
.item2{grid-area:secondCol;}
.gridContainer{display:grid;grid-template-columns: auto auto;}
</style>

<div class="col-md-12">

<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'post__in' => array(659,662,661,660)
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<div class="gridContainer">
<div class="firstCol">
<?php  
$number = 0;

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  $number++;
  global $product;

  // odd?
  if($number % 2 == 1){
    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</a>';
  }    
endwhile;
?>

</div> <!-- End of first col -->

<div class="secondCol">
<?php  
$number = 0;

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    
$number++;
global $product;

  // even?
  if($number % 2 != 1){
    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</a>';
  }

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
</div><!-- End of second col -->
</div><!-- End of grid container -->
```

**Note:** I can't test it, because I don't have all the code, so take this into consideration when testing it, there may be some bugs.